# Tensforflow schedule - does not change boundaries

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I'm trying to manipulate the learning rate with tf PiecewiseConstantDecay.
I can easily check if the algorithm switches learning rate values, because one rate is extremely low 1e-20 !!
However, NO setting of the "boundaries" causes the algorithm to switch learning rate... What am I doing wrong?

```
step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
boundaries = [100]
values = [1e2, 1e-20]

schedule = tf.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(boundaries, values)
lr = 1e-4 * schedule(step)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=100,batch_size=32)
```

Would love your input.

Answer (score 1):

After 100 steps learning rate will switch from 1e-2 to 1e-24.

What exactly is the problem here? Are you confusing steps with epochs?

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested this. With 1e-24 learning is completly stalled. However, after 100 steps learning just continues, implying that we are still learning with 1e-2. I'm glad you think it's correct but It does not seem to work